# Let $\,\displaystyle f \colon [0,1] \to [0,1]$ be continuous and $\,f(0)=0,f(1)=1.$

Tags: real-analysis

I am stuck  on the following problem that says:

> Let $\,\displaystyle f \colon [0,1] \to [0,1]$ be continuous and $\,f(0)=0,f(1)=1.$ Then $f$ is necessarily
>
> 1. injective ,but not surjective
> 2. surjective,but not injective
> 3. bijective
> 4. surjective

I have to determine which of the following options is correct. Can someone help? Thanks and regards to all.

Comment: You can start by drawing possible paths from $(0,0)$ to $(1,1)$ strictly contained in the unit square.

Comment: Can you think of any such functions $f$? That'd be a good place to start...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can kick out 1. and 2. by considering $f(x)=x$. furthermore A function with a graph like the letter $N$  will be not injective.  But the function is surjective due to intermediate value theorem.

Comment: @learner The intermediate value theorem states that if $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function, then for every $\gamma \in [f(a),f(b)]$ there is $\xi \in [a,b]$ such that $f(\xi)=\gamma$.